# Group Pandas data frame by number of rows and create a new column with group number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to identify every x number of rows with a unique id. The last group can take less than x rows if the reminder is smaller than x.

From the example below, I want to create the column `group_id` that attributes an id for every 3 observations.

```
   foo  group_id
0    1  1
1    2  1
2    3  1
3    4  2
4    5  2
5    6  2
6    7  3
7    8  3
8    9  3
9   10  4
```

Comment: `df['group_id'] = np.arange(len(df))//3 + 1`

Answer (score 1):

Another variant which may offer some flexibility :)

**1.** First for what you initially requested:

```
mylist = [[i+1]*3 for i in range(len(df))]
df['group_id'] = np.resize(mylist,len(df))
df
```

| index | foo | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 5 | 2 |
| 5 | 6 | 2 |
| 6 | 7 | 3 |
| 7 | 8 | 3 |
| 8 | 9 | 3 |
| 9 | 10 | 4 |

**2.** What if you would like to attribute `strings`?

```
mylist = [[i]*3 for i in ['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd']]
df['group_id'] = np.resize(mylist,len(df))
df
```

| index | foo | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | aaa |
| 1 | 2 | aaa |
| 2 | 3 | aaa |
| 3 | 4 | bbb |
| 4 | 5 | bbb |
| 5 | 6 | bbb |
| 6 | 7 | ccc |
| 7 | 8 | ccc |
| 8 | 9 | ccc |
| 9 | 10 | ddd |